# how to pass argument to dockerfile from a file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to pass an argument from a file to docker file.

I tried to the copy the file into docker container and use source command.

### Dockerfile

```
COPY docker.env .
RUN /bin/bash -c "source docker.env"
```

### Docker.env

```
BuildMode="release"
```

### another try which also did not work

```
export BuildMode="release"
```

There is no error but when I tried to print `ECHO $BuildMode`, it is not printing the value inside it, it is like it did not get the value inside of it.

But if I create a docker container and try the same codes inside docker container, then it is working.

Comment: So, when will you use the variable?

Answer (score 14):

Then you can use `--build-arg`, it will pass parameters with `--build-arg key=value` to dockerfile when build, refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg).

You just need to use `sed` to get from your env file & combine them to the format `--build-arg key=value` when build the dockerfile, example as next:

**Dockefile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG BuildMode
ENV BuildMode=${BuildMode}

RUN echo $BuildMode
```

**docker.env:**

```
BuildMode="release"
```

**Command:**

```
docker build -t abc:1 $(cat docker.env | sed 's@^@--build-arg @g' | paste -s -d " ") . --no-cache
```

**Output:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/1$ docker build -t abc:1 $(cat docker.env | sed 's@^@--build-arg @g' | paste -s -d " ") . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 13c9f1285025
Step 2/4 : ARG BuildMode
 ---> Running in 3bc49fbb0af4
Removing intermediate container 3bc49fbb0af4
Step 3/4 : ENV BuildMode=${BuildMode}
 ---> Running in 4c253fba0b36
Removing intermediate container 4c253fba0b36
 ---> c70f7f535d1f
Step 4/4 : RUN echo $BuildMode
 ---> Running in 5fef72f28975
"release"
Removing intermediate container 5fef72f28975
 ---> 4b5555223b5b
Successfully built 4b5555223b5b
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

Comment: I miss Linux... I wrote answer for macOS bash because I can't use GNU tools :(

Comment: Nice solution to centralize the version in a resource file. Thanks

Comment: On mac os 12.6 had to modify this part `$(cat docker.env | sed 's@^@--build-arg @g' | paste -s -d " " /dev/stdin)`

Comment: "Just use sed" is an oxymoron. Sed is very hard and no use of it is something that can be qualified with "just".

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with whitespaces and with old [macOS bash version 3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/197172/292944). Since I had to make work for everybody with macOS, I had to make a workaround and came up with this solution

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo $line
  opts+=(--build-arg "$line")
done < ".ENV.FILE"

docker build "${opts[@]}" -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${DTAG} -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${K8S_NS} .
```

Where `.ENV.FILE` looks like this:

```
APP_PORT=3030
APP_HOST=0.0.0.0
APP_API_URL=FOO
APP_API_WHITE=S P A C E
```

I hope it helps somebody

Comment: Word of warning: this will skip the last argument if the env file does not end in a newline. To get around this, try substituting the first line: `while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do`

Comment: ohh that is true, that is why all my files ends with newline. In fact, it's how POSIX standard defines a file.  I'm not sure if we should put this as an answer or not...

Comment: I think it's out of scope for the original question, but just wanted to piggy back on your answer to add that caveat.

Answer (score 0):

final I found the issue, the issue was docker was removing the intermediate container while building so the variable was not stored this happens if the docker build was run using -rm flag.
So the remedy I made was to execute the code in the previous code itself

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source docker.env; echo $Environment'
```

I know it was not a good idea if the code is big but this is the only way if you are using -rm and bash code
------------------------------------------------------(OR)----------------------------------------------------------------

set --rm=false flag and try, but I have not tried that because I have to run with -rm flag as it is the default code in visual code I should not alter it

Answer (score 0):

Every Dockerfile `RUN` command launches a new container in a new shell.  No `export` command you run there will ever have an effect in a later layer.  If you use `.` or non-standard vendor extensions like bash's `source` to read in a script that sets variables, again, that will never have any effect in a later layer.

```sh
FROM busybox
RUN export FOO=foo
CMD echo FOO is $FOO # doesn't actually print a value
```

If you want to set environment variables, you need to use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive.

```sh
FROM busybox
ENV FOO=foo
CMD echo FOO is $FOO
# Compare: docker run -e FOO=bar myimage
```

If it absolutely must be in a file, then you have to read it in on every `RUN` command that depends on variables set there.  You also need to arrange for it to be read in when the container starts; the usual way is to write an `ENTRYPOINT` that reads the environment file and then runs whatever the image's `CMD` is.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am entrypoint.sh

# Read in the environment file
. /env.sh

# Run the CMD, as the main container process
exec "$@"
```

```sh
# I am Dockerfile
FROM busybox
COPY env.sh entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Example: Do something that depends on the variable value
RUN . /env.sh && echo FOO is $FOO
# Need to repeat "." in every RUN line
RUN . /env.sh && echo BAR is $BAR

# Startup-time instructions
ENTRYPOINT ["/env.sh"]  # must use JSON syntax
CMD echo FOO is $FOO
# Compare: docker run -v $PWD/env.sh:/env.sh myimage
```

(For the same reasons, you need to use Docker `WORKDIR` over shell `cd` to persistently switch directories; and you shouldn't use environment managers Python virtual environments, Node's `nvm`, or Ruby's `rvm` in Docker because managing the environment variables is irritating and Docker already provides an isolated execution environment.)

Comment: You need to repeat the `.` command in every `RUN` line that needs the environment file.  I expanded the last example to show this.

Answer (score 0):

in file docker-compose.yml

```
  my-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./python/
      args:
        ARGS_1: aamazonaws.com
        ARGS_2: ggoogle.com
```

in Dockerfile

```
FROM base:latest

ARG ARGS_1
ARG ARGS_2

COPY . /app/$ARGS_1

VOLUME [ "/configs/" ]

ENTRYPOINT [ "" ]

CMD [ "" ]
```

Answer (score -2):

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG BuildMode
ENV BuildMode=${BuildMode}

RUN echo $BuildMode
```

docker.env

```
BuildMode=value
```

You can add many variables in docker.env

`docker build $(cat docker.env | awk -F "=" '{ print "--build-arg " $1"="$2;}' | xargs) -t image_name:latest .`